# Why my Expression Engine default menus don't load?

Tags: ee2

I was running 2.6.1 and I logged in today (hadn’t logged in since june 2013), none of the EE menus are working.  All the menus and buttons at the top do not work anymore.  I upgraded to the latest version flawlessly but yet still none of the buttons or menus are working.  It’s like the AJAX/jquery or whatever they use to show the menus isn't being loaded.

The sidebar will not expand either.  The menus at the bottom of the control panel EE Info, Learning EE, News and Stats, & quick tips wont expand either.

When I edit an Entry none of the buttons work there either, ie: publish, date, ping, pages, revisions, etc.

They all load but there is no effect when I click on them.  Yes I have tried uploading it all again.  I even uploaded it and tried it as fresh install (as a new site) and they still didn't work. I have tried it on IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari. None of the menus works.  It doesn't make any sense to me really.

Comment: Did you upload a fresh `/themes/` folder (with care to keep your `/themes/third_party/` folder intact)?

Comment: I agree this definitely sounds like a theme issue

Comment: Yes, I have deleted it and re uploaded it.  It still wont load the menus.  Also I'm not using any third party stuff that folder was and still is empty.

Comment: If ur using your original EE download files, try downloading fresh set from ellellislabs again. Original files may be corrupt.

Comment: jQuery for control panel enabled?

Comment: I will try re-downloading them from ellis and I will update.  Jquery should have already been enabled. I'm the only admin and it was working ok last time I logged in until the other day.

Comment: do you have any JS errors on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is the solution I finally found thanks to Ellis Lab and my webhost Eleven2. Ellis Lab discovered it was a 403 issue doing some testing on my account and I passed along the information to Eleven2 and they fixed it with the solution below. I hope this helps anyone else hosting on Eleven2 or anywhere else that's having this problem.

It was an issue with the mod_security.

You can give the following lines in the .htaccess file of the account to fix the issue.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last month, the only solution I found was to download the new version 2.7.3 and start with a fresh install... Did you save your template files? It's easy to put it all back if you did!

Sorry can't give you a better solution! But time was running out for my client!